Animated short - brief history of mankind
I saw an animated short film in a UK cinema circa 1982-4.
There was no dialogue. There were sound effects and music score.
Running time between 5 to 10 minutes.
Plot was a brief history of mankind, technology development, and perpetual fighting.
A montage of images included a knights one in black armour, the other in white,  charging at each other, then two heads fall on the ground.  Shots of the Easter Island statues. A perpetual motion machine like this one. Repeated shots of a ticking pendulum clock indicating the passage of time, and a man's face on an early light bulb. Finally, an atomic mushroom cloud, and the light bulb is broken.
It isn't Edifice.
Edit - nor  The History of the World in 3 Minutes Flat
Can you identify it?

Was this as part of a series of short films? This isn't the normal sort of thing one would see in a cinema...

https://youtu.be/nQWq1vcqGEQ?si=sA54IJLY8bVzQjyy

@Valorum, it was a short film accompanying a main feature, possibly Tootsie or Ghostbusters. In the 1970s it used to be a common thing to have a short with the main feature in UK cinemas,  though by the 1980s it had become rare, but not unknown.

Thanks for the suggestion, it isn't The History of the World in 3 Minutes Flat

I kinda got reminded of the music video for do the evolution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDaOgu2CQtI but that wasn't quite it

This is Dilemma (1981).
Edit - this was shown in UK cinemas as a short accompanying Return of the Jedi in 1983.
It's one of a series of theatrical short films shown in British cinemas in the 1970s and 80s



